# How can I highlight a row in Gtk.treeview _without_ selecting it?

Tags: python, treeview, gtk, highlight, gobject

I have a gtk treeview representing the song playback queue for a music player application I am building. I would like to highlight the row of the currently playing song. I know that I can select it in order to highlight it, but I would like to have the current song highlighted, and also allow the user to select another song. I haven't been able to find anyway to accomplish this, I would really appreciate any advice.

```py
import gi 
import sys
gi.require_version ("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class PlaybackQueue():
    def __init__(self):
        #Sets up list store, for now each row only contains a song name
        self.list_store = Gtk.ListStore(str)

        #Sets up treeview
        self.tree_view = Gtk.TreeView(self.list_store)
        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Song", renderer, text = 0)
        self.tree_view.append_column(column)

        self.selection = self.tree_view.get_selection()
    def update_current_song(self):
        #current_song_iter is the iter corresponding to the current song, how do I highlight it in the tree view?
        current_song_iter = self.get_current_song()
        return True
```

[image: [Image of treeview showing selected row and other row I would like to highlight as an example]]

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to create a custom cell renderer which can render ‘currently playing’ differently from ‘selected’. Or add an additional column which (for example) contains an icon in the currently playing row, and nothing in other rows.